# Fatal Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find "librenderscript-toolkit.so"

Tags: android, crash, native, renderscript

I'm facing a crash on console with this native library. I've imported this library as a module in project. I think, maybe I'm missing something with `NDK`.

##### Crash Trace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/photocollage.photoeditor.layout.collagemaker.photo.grid-26CYJoq73H483tupCrzMjg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.app-26CYJoq73H483tupCrzMjg==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /hw_product/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]] couldn't find "librenderscript-toolkit.so"
       at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1067)
       at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1007)
       at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1668)
       at com.google.android.renderscript.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.kt:1097)
       at FragmentABC.updateBlurBg(FragmentABC.kt:353)
       at FragmentABC.updateBlurBg$default(FragmentABC.kt:351)
       at FragmentABC.initBlurBg(FragmentABC.kt:334)
       at FragmentABC.checkDefaultSettings(FragmentABC.java:316)
       at FragmentABC.access$checkDefaultSettings(FragmentABC.java:56)
       at FragmentABC$initCollage$1.onGlobalLayout(FragmentABC.kt:308)
       at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnGlobalLayout(ViewTreeObserver.java:1056)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2858)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1876)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8167)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1057)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:875)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:776)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1042)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:900)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8349)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1055)
```